# cannot drop existing db2 database

Tags: db2

`db2 list database directory` gives me

```
Database 1 entry:

 Database alias                       = M
 Database name                        = M
 Local database directory             = /var/lib/edumate/database
 Database release level               = d.00
 Comment                              =
 Directory entry type                 = Indirect
 Catalog database partition number    = 0
 Alternate server hostname            =
 Alternate server port number         =
```

buuuuut

`db2 drop database M` gives me

```
SQL1013N  The database alias name or database name "M       " could not be 
found.  SQLSTATE=42705
```

and `/var/lib/edumate/database/db2inst1/NODE0000` doesn't have `M` directory

any suggestion on how I can `remove` the database m from the system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
db2 uncatalog database M
```

Comment: I get `SQL0965W  There is no message text corresponding to SQL warning "77" in the 
message file on this workstation.  The warning was returned from module 
"SQL09072" with original tokens "".`

Comment: Not sure why it didn't work before but it worked today :-) Thank you.

Comment: And it doesn't work today :-)

Comment: Check the db directory (db2 list db directory) to see what it is cataloged. Also, take a look at the instance directory to see the databases defined there (the catalog tablespaces). With these two information you will know if there are still files for a database.

Comment: It happened again :-( created support ticket with IBM support.